# Integrate "adb uninstall" to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I want to integrate "adb uninstall" to eclipse. I switch to

1. "External Tools Configurations"->"New launch Configuration"
2. (Right Tab)"Location" set to "path/to/adb.exe"
3. "Working directory" leave empty
4. "Arguments" set to "uninstall ${project_name}"

`${project_name}` doesn't returns `com.my.project.`
Which variable I need to specify in second argument instead of `${project_name}` ?

From command line it looks like "`adb uninstall com.my.project`"

Answer (score 0):

its actually

```
adb uninstall packagename
```

In android, each application is uniquely identified by package name, hence we specify packagename here.

But i am not sure how to get packagename in configurations.
In code, you get it from

```
getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).packageName
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this site to fix it...[here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html) and [here.](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html).